# MySQL Join with empty count

Tags: mysql, join

I want to count all items in table stock, also the empty ones.
But i can show only the full ones, i tried with several tuts, but it wasnt working.

Table products:

- id
- status

Table stock:

- id
- pid (product id)
- status

My mySQL query:

```
SELECT p.id , COUNT( p.id ) AS pcount
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN stock s ON p.id = s.pid
WHERE s.status=1
  AND p.status=1
GROUP BY p.id    
ORDER BY pcount
```

May there is something wrong with the logics, because on empty stock the s.status will never be 1... But dont get behind..
May i need OUTER JOIN or similar?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding your WHERE s.Status=1 is turning your query into an INNER JOIN.  Move that condition to the LEFT JOIN portion

```
SELECT 
      p.id, 
      COUNT( s.pid ) AS pcount
   FROM 
      products p
         LEFT JOIN stock s 
            ON p.id = s.pid
           AND s.status = 1
   WHERE 
      p.status = 1
   GROUP BY 
      p.id    
   ORDER BY 
      pcount
```

Comment: It was exactly the problem. I searched hours, and get here the answer in mins.. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to count for the number of lines in stock referring to each product, try this :

```
SELECT p.id , COUNT( s.id ) AS pcount
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN stock s ON p.id = s.pid
WHERE s.status=1
AND p.status=1
GROUP BY p.id    
ORDER BY pcount
```

Comment: This seems pretty much the same output, it counts the lines, but the empty lines are not countet. Or at least not set in pcount..

Comment: What's empty line for you? a line without stock?

Comment: Yes, empty stock was meant. But problem solved. Thanks anyway!